Property does not exist on type ts(2339) Reactjs, Nextjs, useActionState
Im using useActionState (useFormState) to handle form validation.
I have declared the initialState like this
export default function Form() {
  const initialState = { message: "", errors: {} };
  const [state, dispatch] = useActionState(createProduct, initialState); 
return (
    <form action={dispatch} className="space-y-5">
// other form fields...

However, when I try to display the errors like this under the input field
<div id="product-error" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true">
          {state.errors?.productName &&
            state.errors.productName.map((error: string) => (
              <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-red-500" key={error}>
                {error}
              </p>
            ))}
        </div>

I got this error: Property 'errors' does not exist on type '{ message: string; }'.ts(2339)
For reference, here's the createProduct function:
export type ProductState = {
  errors?: {
    productName: string[],
    brand: string[],
    imageURL: string[],
    productDescription: string[],
    stockQuantity: string[],
    retailPrice: string[],
    COGS: string[],
    hasVariants: string[],
    variants: string[],
    warehouse_enter_date: string[],
    exp_date: string[],
  };
  message?: string | null;
};

export async function createProduct(
  prevState: ProductState,
  formData: FormData
) {
...
// in this body I call API to fetch product data
}

I don't understand why have clearly defined the initialState to contain both message and errors property, but ts complains that there's no errors property?
